# Android minimum API in beta tests

Tags: android, google-play, intel-xdk, beta-testing, crosswalk

My game is now in beta tests. I want it to be available for devices with Android 4.4 and up. I've set the minimum android API to 19, but on my app Google Play site the requirement stays 4.0+.

Does minimum API requirement work for alpha/beta apps?

It's a Crosswalk app, APK made with IntelXDK. I've also checked XML config files, and they all seem to be ok (android-minSdkVersion is set to 19) so it looks like Google bug. Is it a known issue?

Comment: What value do you see when you inspect the built package? It could be the Crosswalk builder is overwriting this value. Also, are you building with CLI 5.1.1 and CW15 or with CLI 4.1.2? I would trust the CLI 5.1.1 CW builder to do the right thing, the CLI 4.1.2 builders use an obsolete build technique over which you have less control.

Comment: Than you for your reply. I use CLI 5.1.1. What do you mean by inspect the build package? I have never done that. Is it something I can do with Intel XDK or by some external software?

Comment: You have to use an external tool like apktool or aapt (which is part of Android Studio). I'm sure there are others out there. In essence, you need a tool that will allow you to inspect the AndroidManifest.xml file inside the APK file.

Comment: Thanks again @xmnboy! I've decompiled an APK with apktool. AndroidManifest.xml file doesn't say much regarding minSdkVersion. However there is a config.xml file and it looks allright "<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />".

I doubt that API versioning has changed :). So it clearly looks like a Google bug! Or should I check any other config as well?

Comment: Interesting. There is one other parameter, I don't recall what it is named, and I don't think you can set it via the `config.xml` file because it relates to some element of the version of the build system (Android system libs, or something like that). It might also have an impact on this, but I would expect that API level to be higher than 19... if I get some time I'll do some experimentation.

Comment: Much appreciated @xmnboy! I've also sent a ticket to Google via Developer Console with some screenshots end explanation. Let's see if they have something to say about this situation. I have searched through the files for something like "libs" but can't see anything similiar.